# Speed up VBA execution

Tags: performance, excel, macros, excel-2013, vba

So I have the below VBA macros setup and when CompHide runs it takes several minutes to update. I feel like this is due to the line that says C.EntireRow.Columns(43).Value = ""

I tried making a new "helper" column that would check if both of the columns were empty and had it return "Y" or "N" and then had the macro look at that for "Y" and hide those. This sped it up some but I am wanting to get even faster if I could.

Orginal code:

```
Sub CompHide()

    Dim sht As Worksheet, C As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Set sht = Sheets("Comparison")
        sht.Rows.Hidden = False

    CSetRowVis "C9", "CMarket1"
    CSetRowVis "C115", "CMarket2"
    CSetRowVis "C221", "CMarket3"
    CSetRowVis "C329", "CMarket4"
    CSetRowVis "C437", "CMarket5"
    CSetRowVis "C545", "CMarket6"
    CSetRowVis "C653", "CMarket7"
    CSetRowVis "C761", "CMarket8"
    CSetRowVis "C869", "CMarket9"
    CSetRowVis "C977", "CMarket10"

    For Each C In sht.Range("CNonTest")
        If C.Value = "" And C.EntireRow.Columns(43).Value = "" Then
            C.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next

    sht.Range("CBlank").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub CSetRowVis(addr As String, rngName As String)
    With Sheets("Comparison")
        If .Range(addr).Value = "Unused" Then
            .Range(rngName).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

New Code:

```
Sub CompHide()

    Dim sht As Worksheet, C As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Set sht = Sheets("Comparison")
        sht.Rows.Hidden = False

    CSetRowVis "C9", "CMarket1"
    CSetRowVis "C115", "CMarket2"
    CSetRowVis "C221", "CMarket3"
    CSetRowVis "C329", "CMarket4"
    CSetRowVis "C437", "CMarket5"
    CSetRowVis "C545", "CMarket6"
    CSetRowVis "C653", "CMarket7"
    CSetRowVis "C761", "CMarket8"
    CSetRowVis "C869", "CMarket9"
    CSetRowVis "C977", "CMarket10"

    For Each C In sht.Range("CHideTest")
        If C.Value = "Y" Then
            C.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next

    sht.Range("CBlank").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub CSetRowVis(addr As String, rngName As String)
    With Sheets("Comparison")
        If .Range(addr).Value = "Unused" Then
            .Range(rngName).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

This is using Excel 2013 Standard 64 bit. Number of rows is just under 1200. Number of Columns is 150. All of those cells are formulas

If there is any extra info you need let me know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Code Review

Comment: Code Review is a thing? I did not know this. Can you point me the URL sir

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: @MacroMan Thanks for the referral, but it would be more helpful to give a rule that actually explains why it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. (Namely, there is no specific programming problem to be solved, but a request for suggestions to improve the code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
For Each C In sht.Range("CHideTest")
    If C.Value = "Y" Then
        C.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next
```

consider something like this:

```
Dim rng As Range 'for collecting rows to be hidden

For Each C In sht.Range("CHideTest")
    If C.Value = "Y" Then
        if rng Is Nothing Then
            set rng = C
        Else
            set rng = application.union(rng, C)
        end if
    End If
Next

'hide all accumulated rows (if any found)
if not rng is nothing then rng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Comment: in addition, convert the `If C.Value = "Y"` bit to a variant array

Comment: I will test this later this week. Work has assigned a bigger project I have to work on at the moment so had to backburner this.

Comment: Was able to test and it drops the execution time to 30 secs. i see some other code I might be able to trim to speed it even more thanks for the help.